# Linked List in C that runs correctly in Visual Studio but not in Linux

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linked-list

I am completely baffled by my c code for a linked list. The code works correctly in visual studio but NOT in Linux. Code is below

```
typedef struct map 
{
    char key[50];
    char value[50];
    struct map* next;
} map_t;

void AddEntry( map_t** head, char* key, char* value )
{
    map_t* newEntry = (map_t*)malloc(sizeof(map_t) );
    strcmp( newEntry->key,  key);
    strcmp( newEntry->value, value);
    newEntry->next = NULL;

    if ( *head == NULL )
    {
        *head = newEntry;
    }
    else
    {
        map_t** currentEntry = head;

        while ( (*currentEntry)->next != NULL )
        {
            *currentEntry = (*currentEntry)->next;
        }

       (*currentEntry)->next = newEntry;
    }
}
```

Here's my call:

```
map_t* localListHead = NULL;
AddEntry( &localListHead, "??", "Test" );
```

Anyone see something I'm not seeing?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work correctly in Linux? What compiler (GCC) ?  Does it compile, or do you get compiler errors? Does the program crash / give an error message?  You need to be **much** more explicit - we are not wizards (not all of us, anyway)

Comment: Why are you calling strcmp? Do you mean strcpy?

Comment: By the way, if you wrote strcmp because you typed this in by hand, please don't do that. Always copy and paste code because it is far too easy to make a mistake, which makes it impossible for others to find the real problems.

Comment: Another comment: I see you are running to the end of the list each time you call AddEntry. Consider how slowly this would work if you had a list of 50,000 items or a million. I'd keep a pointer to the last item in your map structure, or add the new entries to the front of the list instead. All depends on how this is intended to be used of course.

Comment: Sorry. Yes I'm using GCC. The strcmp is a typo. The issue I'm seeing is that when I check the members of localListHead after calling AddEntry they're garbage values. This was a quick write up I did. I was going to optimize traversing once I resolved this issue. I'm new to C but have C++ experience

Comment: This is my first time using Stack Overflow by the way

Comment: Also to add when I check the value of localListHead it has the correct address of the structure created in the method

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong about this but it seems that the code in your else block has a problem. You declare a `map_t** currentEntry` assigned to `head` and then write into it. Why do you do that?

As far as I can tell what you really want there is a `map_t* currentEntry = *head`.

Comment: my concern is for the if block. I haven't tested subsequent nodes since the root isn't working

Comment: So I got it to work but still don't understand why the former still runs correctly in Visual Studio. I changed the char arrays in the structure to char pointer

    typedef struct map 
    {
     char* key;
     char* value;
     struct map* next;
    } map_t

And changed the assignment of them in the method

    newEntry->key = key;
    newEntry->value = value;

It now returns valid values. Just starting in C but man is this language a headache

Comment: @user1553132: If you learn assembly language first C is a breeze.